# I2C: How to write to a 16-bit register address using i2cset

Tags: i2c

Trying to write a byte to a 16-bit address on an I2C device (OV5640 camera) using `i2cset`.  I can successfully read from the device registers using the following sequence (read byte from device address 0x3c and register address 0x3030):

```
i2cset -v -f 1 0x3c 0x30 0x30
i2cget -v -f 1 0x3c
```

To write to the device, I use this sequence (write byte 0x40 to device address 0x3c and register address 0x3030):

```
i2cset -v -f 1 0x3c 0x30 0x30
i2cset -v -f 1 0x3c 0x40
```

This sequence does not show any errors but when the address is read again, the value is unchanged.
Can anyone provide any insight on the correct i2cset syntax to use when writing to this device?

Answer (score 4):

SOLVED! I found the solution for this and it requires using the `i2cset` block write option (`i`) as follows:

```
i2cset -y -f 2 0x3c 0x30 0x30 0x40 i
```

This command writes the value 0x40 to register address 0x3030 at device address 0x3c.

Answer (score 0):

i2ctransfer -y 2 w5@0x3C [register address] [byte3] [byte2] [byte1] [byte0]

where:
w5 is the command for writing 5 bytes to device at I2C address 0x3C;
[register address] is the 8-bit address of the register where [byte3] is to be stored;
[bytex] are the bytes that will be written in consecutive registers. (The internal address pointer in the device will be automatically incremented after each byte write!) You can also send the four bytes to a 16-bit register address by spitting the register address into two separate bytes: first the high byte, then the low byte. Also increment 5 to 6, because SIX bytes have to be send to the I2C device: the first two are the 16-bit register address, followed by the four data bytes.